# PD4ML issue while converting an HTML that contains Chinese characters

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pd4ml

While using PD4ML for pdf creation, I have noticed that there is a problem with HTMLs that contain Chinese characters.
Those characters are Chinese and can be seen in their normal form in the source html.

snippet from pdf:

[image: snippet from pdf]

Comment: How do you convert your HTML to PDF using PDFBox?

Comment: PDFBox does not contain anything to convert from HTML to PDF. So there's a tool above that you've been using / developed. To find out if this is a PDFBox problem, you'd need to create a software that uses PDFBox only.

Comment: The PDFBox wasn't relevant. The pdf generator is PD4ML and the problem was that a suitable font file which can handle Chines was not in place. Added SimSun font file and updated the PD4ML properties file and that worked for me.

Comment: @VictorV Glad to hear that. Please create an answer (this is OK) with what you did (with enough details that may help others) or delete your question.